# What is the best way to write a stored procedure with FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

```
[Migration(1)]
public class TestCreateUserTable : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Execute.Script("myscriptUP.sql");
        Execute.EmbeddedScript("myscriptUP.sql");
        Execute.Sql("CREATE TABLE Users");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Execute.Script("myscriptDOWN.sql");
        Execute.EmbeddedScript("myscriptDOWN.sql");
        Execute.Sql("DELETE TABLE Users");
    }
}
```

myscriptUP.sql

```
"CREATE TABLE Users"
```

myscriptDOWN.sql

```
"DELETE TABLE Users"
```

when I can use Script, EmbeddedScript or SQL?

Comment: It is my understanding that the reason for FluentMigrator is to NOT write stored procedures although I have not used it.

Comment: I agree, fluent is not the best way to deal with stored procedures. but to manage the versioning of the db, do you see other solutions?

Comment: Depends upon the database type.  We use SQL server and have a separate solution in Visual Studio with projects for each database specifically for that; includes all the views, sp's, tables, udf etc. and publish from there depending upon which environment we want to apply it to (we have several such as QA, UA, Production etc)